# Php MySql unknown error

Tags: php, mysql

Hi here i have problem with this script above... It does the thing but returning error.. it  makes changes to database correctly but returning Error... Do i have mistake somewhere?

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO student (fullname, username, password, group_id) 
     VALUES ('$fullname', '$username', '$password', '$group_id')"
);

if ($result == 'true'){

    $caturi =  $group_id;
    if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {

        foreach ($_POST['subject'] as $cat) {
            $values[]  = sprintf (
                "(%d, '%s')", 
                intval($cat), 
                mysql_real_escape_string($caturi)
            );
        }
        $result2 = "INSERT INTO list (subject_a, group_a) 
                    VALUES " . join(',', $values);
        mysql_query($result2);

    }   

    echo '<p align="center" style="color:#ccc;">Success...</p>';
}
else{
    echo "Error...";
}
```

Comment: You should try to see if you actually have a MySQL using `mysql_error()`

Comment: Please could you change `echo "Error...";` to `echo "Error... " . mysql_error( );`. This will give you some info about the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query()` would return boolean `true` if executed successfully, not a string.

Therefore you must change

`if ($result == 'true')`

to

`if ($result == true)` or shorter - `if ($result)`

---

Please do not use `mysql_*` functions, because they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MYSQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

Comment: Your first correction should not have the quotes around `true` (I think this was a typo given the accompanying text).

Comment: +1 for the answer. I'd +1 you again if I could for the comment regarding usage of the deprecated functions!

Comment: Note that this is note likely the problem as with a loose comparison `true == 'true'` would evaluate as `true`.  A truly more correct approach here would be to use a strict comparison `if(true === $result)`.